# Rails Savon gem keys in upper and lower case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

I'm using the Savon gem to access a SOAP API. The thing is, the API requires keys in uppercase and other keys in lowercase, so I can't use the option `convert_request_keys_to` parameter.

This is the format of the API I need to comply to:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="XmlServices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <xs:GetRooms>
         <xs:request>
             <xs:Credentials> 
                 <xs:Credential1>"example1"</xs:Credential1>
                 <xs:Credential2>"example2"</xs:Credential2>
                 <xs:Credential3>"example3"</xs:Credential3>
         </xs:Credentials>
     </xs:request>
 </xs:GetRooms>
```

As you can see `request` is lowercase, and all the rest is uppercase.

This is how I use the gem:

```
def call(method, attributes = nil)
  attributes = { 'request': { 'Credentials': attributes } }
  response = client.call(method, message: attributes)
  #do something with response
end
```

Am I calling it right? Is there any option I'm missing? Will I need to fork the repository and modify the gem myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, actually this was pretty simple:

Just needed to use the option `convert_request_keys_to :none`